# jQuery render html from Rails view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using jQuery in my Rails project to respond to an AJAX call. I want to replace some html with the updated html (from a partial).

`$('#cart').html('<%= render(@cart) %>')`

This doesn't work, and when I check FireBug, it expands out to:

```
$('#cart').html('<h1>multiple
    lines
    <a href="of">html</a>
    </h1>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#cart').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)).html_safe %>')
```